# Allow multiple decimal separator with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a small project with a POSTR request which expect multiple fields with 2 floats.

My backend expect "." as the decimal separator. However my audience is French and will most probably use "," as decimal separator. Since I don't want to add a small note on my frontend so I tried below code updates to make sure my backend get the dot no matter what is used by the user - without success I'm afraid...

Any ideas ? Thank you !

```
const dotedSize = size.replace(",", ".");
const dotedWeight = weight.replace(",", ".");
```

POST request:

```
const response = await apiInstance.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/create_vote`, {
          first_name,
          last_name,
          gender,
          size: parseFloat(dotedSize),
          weight: parseFloat(dotedWeight),
          birthday: dateTimeToSend,
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `<input type="number" />`, I don't think you need to manually parse/convert float number based on the user's locale.

When the element's value is accessed, the number should be converted to one with dot as decimal separator.

[image]

Here's a jsfiddle to try out: https://jsfiddle.net/rg2wvkn3/. You can change your locale settings in Chrome by doing: Settings > Languages > some other language. I had changed to French/France, hence, the console logged "fr-FR".

---

But if you're not using input with number type,

You can first check user's locale using [Intl.Numberformat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to get the user's locale then convert the string accordingly.

```
const userLocale = navigator.language
const decimalSep = new Intl.NumberFormat(userLocale).format(0.1) === '0,1' ? ',' : '.'

let input = "9999,999"
if(decimalSep === ',') {
  input = input.replace(',', '.')
}

const results = parseFloat(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it the other way around, i.e. to work with numbers everywhere (including your backend) and only format it when displaying the values to the user.

To format a number accordingly you can use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` ([src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)):

```
const val = 1234567.89

// use the user's configured locale
console.log(val.toLocaleString()) // outputs "1,234,567.89" in my case

// use a specific locale
console.log(val.toLocaleString('fr-FR')) // outputs "1 234 567,89"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if the decimal separator is a comma. If it is, just reverse the thousands and decimal separators, remove the thousands separator and any other non-numeric characters, and convert the string to a number.

```js
// Parse string values
console.log(parseNumberInput("€9.999.999,999", 'fr-ca'));
console.log(parseNumberInput("$9,999,999.999"));

// Parse input value
console.log(parseNumberInput(document.getElementById('amount').value, 'fr-ca'));

// No parsing needed
console.log(document.getElementById('amount2').valueAsNumber);

function parseNumberInput(input, locale) {
  const userLocale = locale ?? navigator.language;
  const usesCommaSeparator = new Intl.NumberFormat(userLocale).format(0.1) === '0,1';
  const decimalSep = usesCommaSeparator ? /,/g : /\./g;
  const thousandsSep = usesCommaSeparator ? /\./g : /,/g;
  return Number(input.replace(thousandsSep, '').replace(decimalSep, '.').replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
}
```

```html
<input id="amount" type="text" value="$9.999.999,999" />
<input id="amount2" type="number" value="9999999.999" />
```